# ListView not updating after elements added to bound ObservableCollection (Xamarin)

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, observablecollection

I found many similar questions on StackOverflow, but can't seem to figure out this issue.

I'm trying to bind an ObservableCollection to a ListView so that when the contents of the collection change the ListView will automatically update. Unfortunately, when elements are added to the collection (via button click), the ListView isn't being updated. How can I make the ListView reflect the current contents of the collection?

Note: It seems that if I force layout with `listView.RequestLayout();` the listView will contain the correct number of items. However, it won't necessarily contain the *right* items. For example, if I delete the first item and add a new one at the end, forcing a layout has no effect.  If I force the layout after deleting the first item, then again after adding one at the end, the contents are correct.

**Activity code**

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    int count = 1;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        ObservableCollection<UserTask> allTasksCollection = new ObservableCollection<UserTask>();
        while(count < 6)
        {
            allTasksCollection.Add(new UserTask("Task number " + count));
            count++;
        }

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Bind listview to all tasks
        ListView listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.allTasksListView);
        UserTaskListAdapter adapter = new UserTaskListAdapter(this, allTasksCollection);
        listView.Adapter = adapter;

        // Button click should add a new task and remove the first task. 
        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.myButton);
        button.Click += delegate {                
            allTasksCollection.Add(new UserTask("Task number " + count));
            button.Text = string.Format("{0} tasks!", count++);
        };
    }
}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class UserTaskListAdapter : BaseAdapter<UserTask>
{
    Activity context;
    ObservableCollection<UserTask> list;

    public UserTaskListAdapter(Activity _context, ObservableCollection<UserTask> _list)
    : base()
    {
        this.context = _context;
        this.list = _list;
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return list.Count; }
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override UserTask this[int index]
    {
        get { return list[index]; }
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null)
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.UserTaskRowItem, parent, false);

        UserTask item = this[position];
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Title).Text = item.Name;

        return view;
    }
}
```

**Main XAML**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/allTasksContainer">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/myButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hello" />
            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/allTasksListView" />
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**ListItem XAML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutHorizontal">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/CheckboxContainer">
            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/checkboxSelect" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/TextContainer">
            <TextView
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Title" />
            <TextView
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/DueDate" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call NotifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter after updating its items, AFAIK ListView in Android doesn't observe the changes on your ObservableCollection:

Try this code:

```
    button.Click += delegate {                
        allTasksCollection.Add(new UserTask("Task number " + count));
        button.Text = string.Format("{0} tasks!", count++);
        adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
    };
```

You can also try to add a litener to your ObservableCollection, in your adapter, change the constructor to this:

```
this.list.CollectionChanged += (sender,args) => { NotifyDataSetChanged(); };
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Hichaam! Both solutions you provided give me the results I was looking for. I think the second one is probably the better solution, I will use that.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. It will warn the listview that variables within an object within the listview have changed.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/

Edit: misread your question. My bad.

Comment: Yes, I think the objects inside the collection will have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged eventually. That shouldn't matter for adding/removing things from the collection though.. from what I understand the ObservableCollection should be handling this.

Comment: @pulekies This is correct. The listview should see them. I will look at this again later, maybe I can help.